# Finding the covariance matrix of two random gaussian vectors and their characteristic function

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, random-matrices, gaussian

Let $(W,Z)$ be the gaussian random variable vector that we want to find its covariance matrice and characteristic function.

We have $(X,Y)$ a guassian random variable vector with a mean of $m=(1,2)$ and a covariance matrix: $$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    4 & 1  \\
    1 & 4\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

We have that $Z=2X+Y-2$ and $W=\alpha$X+Y.

**How do I calculate the covariance matrix of Z and W?**

I calculated the following :

The expected value of W is $\alpha +2$.

The expected value of Z is $2$

and both of their characteristics functions.

**How to calculate the characteristic function of $(W,Z)$ given both of their characteristic function and we don't know anything about their independency?**

Answer (score 0):

$E(ZW)=E(2X+Y-2) (\alpha X+Y)=2\alpha E(X^{2}+2E(XY)+\alpha (XY)+E(Y^{2})-2\alpha EX-2EY$ You know $EX$ and$EY$. Now $E(XY)=4
$, $EX^{2}=5$ and $EY^{2}=8$. Independence is not required in this calculation. Finally, the covariance of $Z$ and $W$ is $E(ZW)-(EZ)(EW)$.

Comment: I'm asking about the covariance matrix of the two vectors, is it calculated the same way?

Comment: @wageeh Yes., $EZ^{2}$ and $EW^{2}$ can be calculated is a similar way and then you can use the equations $var (Z)=EZ^{2}-(EZ)^{2}, var (W)=EW^{2}-(EW)^{2}$